# How do I use a variable in an FTP shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting, command-line, ftp

Using a handy script that I found for FTP-ing, I modified it to my own use, and it works, but too well, or too literally.

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST='10.0.1.110'
USER='myName'
PASSWD='myPass'
FILE='*.sql' # WILDCARD NOT WORKING - Takes literal string of '*.sql'

# Stripped unrelated code

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
prompt
binary
cd Desktop/SweepToDiskBK
mput /home/myAcct/SQLbackups/"$FILE" "$FILE"
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit
```

That is, the file(s) that gets 'put', is named `*.sql`, and replaces any previous versions of it, instead of `file1.sql`, `file2.sql`, etc.  In the original script, they were doing a `put`, instead of an `mput`, and with a single file names `text.txt`.  I've also tried changing the single quotes after `FILE`, to double quotes, and got the same result.  Can someone let me in on the 'trick' to using variables for CLI FTP-ing?

Thanks in advance,
LO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
FILE=*.sql
```

without any quotes enabling wildcard expansion
and:

```
mput /home/myAcct/SQLbackups/"$FILE"
```

with just one $FILE

Comment: Without the quotes worked for the first part, but I had to have the two `"$FILE"`s to make it work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

But i think you can just do `mput /home/myAcct/SQLbackups/$FILE` to `mput *.sql`? Or if you need to put several files with put, then you need to do it one by one with some sort of a loop.

To check what the script does, change `ftp -n $HOST` to `cat`. Try these very commands in the plain ftp session. Do they work?